# Riemann integrable proof and notation

Tags: integration, analysis, notation

For Riemann integrable proof, I see $f \in \Re(\alpha)$. Also I see $U(p,f,\alpha)$.
What does $\alpha$ stand for?
Also to prove Riemann integrability, what do I do at very first step?
I know my questions sound stupid  but I do need help to understand the materials.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is used to denote the density function  in a Riemann-Stjeltjes integral.
The Riemann-Stjeltjes integral is a generalization of the ordinary Riemann Integral.  Given a function $\alpha$, we sum $f(x_i) (\alpha(x_{i+1}) - \alpha(x_i))$ over our partition instead of $f(x_i)$.

To prove Riemann Integrability, start with given $\epsilon > 0$.  Then prove that there exists $\delta$ so that for any two partitions with mesh size less than $\delta$, the difference between the riemann (-Stjeltjes) sums is less than $\epsilon$. (This is Cauchy's criterion).  One can also work out what the integral is and show that the riemann sums converge to that value.

Comment: Can you explain for the $\alpha$ part again? I still don't get it.